# Iframe is not spanning full width

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm currently using a an iframe inside the modal to display some information. However, this iframe refuses to take the full height and width of its container. 
Here is what I have now:

[image: What I've now]

This first bit of code is the CSS for the modal the iframe is inside of

```
.uiModalContent {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 900px;
  height: 550px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: #222222 1px solid;
}
```

This  is what the iframe has

```
<iframe id="ifrmEmail" class="resizeableIframe" name="ifrmEmail" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="242" width="100%"></iframe>
```

I've changed the height and width to 100% however when I do so, the `uiModalContent` gets a scroll bar which isnt ideal. Does anybody know a work around?

Comment: It's not the `padding` on .uiModalContent that bothers you?

Comment: can u send me demo link?

Comment: thats not a main issue for me no.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the padding you have for **.uiModalContent**, or set it to `0`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oawcu0z8/1/).

Answer (score 0):

give Position: absolute;, Width and height to 100%,

```
.uiModalContent {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: #222222 1px solid;
}
```